# linux shell patch commands

Tags: linux, shell, scripting

As i am new to linux, what is meaning of following scripts :-

```
wget http://downloads.architechboards.com/deposit/microZed_wilink8.config -O .config
```

What I know is that it will download from http://downloads.architechboards.com/microZed_wilink8.config. But what I am not getting is what is meaning of `-O .config`.

What is `patch -p1 < microZed_wilink8.patch`  and what it will do?

Answer (score 1):

1) from `man wget`

> The documents will not be written to the appropriate files, but all will be concatenated together and written to file.

2) from `man patch`

> patch  takes  a  patch file patchfile containing a difference listing produced by the diff program and applies those differences to one or more original files, producing patched versions.

and

> -pnum  or  --strip=num
>
> Strip  the  smallest  prefix  containing  num  leading slashes from each file name found in the patch file.